# Program sometimes can't find merged dependency

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, ilmerge

I have a small applciation which grabs some files from SharePoint, converts them to PDFs and then merges all of the pdfs together into one pdf.

The slowest part of the program is the conversion of each of the files, so when testing `MergePdfs`, the code looks like this:

```
var test = true;
CoverPage.Create(ref orderedListPdfFileNames);
var fileInfo = WordFileInformation.Get(ref orderedListPdfFileNames);

if (test)
    { ConsoleMessage("Skipping Conversion Step for faster testing", ConsoleColor.Cyan);}
else { ConvertPdfs(fileInfo); }

try
{
    MergePdfs();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ConsoleMessage($"{ex.Message} \n\n {ex.InnerException} \n\n {ex.Data}", ConsoleColor.Red);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

if (test)
    { ConsoleMessage("Skipping pdf deletion for faster testing", ConsoleColor.Cyan); }
else { DeletePdfs(); }

ConsoleMessage("Done!", ConsoleColor.Green);
Console.ReadLine();
```

So the code skips `ConvertPdfs` and just grabs the already converted documents and merges them.

This seems to work fine after calling `ILMerge` on the assembly with `itextsharp.dll`.

However, if I change to `var test = false;`, then I get an error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So clearly it can't find `itextsharp.dll` (from the [nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) that itextsharp has no dependencies)

Not only did I merge `itextsharp.dll` into my assembly, but when I call this library after skipping the `ConvertPdfs` it works totally fine.

How is this possible?

Let me know if I should post more of the code

---

Here is my post release batch file, which shows how I am merging the dependencies:

```
CMD
SET parameter=%1
CD %1
ECHO "Copying temporary file..."
COPY PdfConverter.exe temp.exe
ECHO "Copying query file..."
COPY ..\..\camlquery.txt camlquery.txt
ECHO "Merging dependancies..."
"..\..\ILMerge.exe" /out:"PdfConverter.exe" /copyattrs /targetPlatform:"v4" "temp.exe" "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" "itextsharp.dll" 
ECHO "Removing temporary file..."
DEL temp.exe
```

Comment: you do have all the dlls present in the Debug / Release folder right?

Comment: @Eric Yes - I think found the issue. I was copying my config file into `App.Publish` to test whether the merged assembly was working on its own (without the dlls present). However, as you can see from the post-build batch file above, the merged assembly is not copied to that folder, so I just needed to use the one which was in `bin\release`